# How to hide the keyboard menu in macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, keyboard, accessibility, input-source

How can I disable/hide/remove the shortcut to the keyboards?
I have only a single input method selected () and I don't need this menu as it takes away valuable real-estate before the icons hiding behind the camera area!

[image: Menu shortcut to the keyboards]

I have checked there is only a single input source: System Settings > Keyboard > Text Input > Input Sources

Also in System Settings > Accessibility > De-selected the Accessibility Keyboard

[image: Also System Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources > Show Input Menu in Menu bar] should solve.

Still no luck. Can someone point out to a better way to hide/remove this keyboard shortcut please?

Comment: Which version of Ventura do you have installed and what's the exact model of your Mac?

Comment: Works fine on Sonoma.

Answer (score 5):

Go to ->System Settings->Keyboard. In the Text Input section, click on the Edit button for Input Sources and turn off "Show Input menu in menu bar". See the Apple support webpage "[Change Input Sources settings on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/guide/mac-help/mchl84525d76/mac)" for more.

You can also reach this setting by searching for "input menu" in Spotlight assuming "System Settings" is included among the search results in your [Spotlight settings](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/guide/mac-help/mchl3fd7fc15/13.0/mac/13.0).

Albeit at slightly different locations, this setting has been available for many years.

Comment: Yes this pretty much should be working right out of the box by the sounds of it, which really didn't for me. Hence had to go on a hunt for the answers. What I found working was the CMD + drag-out-of-the-menu as the working one. Hence my answer below. But thanks for your response. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. However, it is better if you include in your question what you have tried and did not work the next time. In addition, it is a bit abnormal for this feature not to work. It is possible that one of the programs on your computer that does not come with macOS by default is interfering with the computer's settings and it may help to find out that program.

Comment: Thanks. I've done it now.

Comment: Happy to hear that you have found a workaround but I suggest you restart and login under the [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-bh/guide/mac-help/mh21245/mac) and see if the setting works. If it works under the safe mode, it means one of the programs that starts automatically when you login normally might be the culprit. If the setting does not work under the safe mode either, create a new user and see if the setting works when you login with it right after. If the setting still does not work, you may consider reinstalling macOS eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a Apple forum member (I list the threads below) here's how: CMD + Drag-the-icon-off the menu bar.

How to rid-off the accessibility keyboard… - Apple Community
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255061119?answerId=259414067022

Use the Accessibility Keyboard on Mac – Apple Support (AU)
https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchlc74c1c9f/13.0/mac/13.0

Change Input Sources settings on Mac – Apple Support (AU)
https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchl84525d76/mac